# Search Python dictionary where value is list

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

If I had a dictionary where the value was set to a list by default, how could I go about searching all of these lists in the dictionary for a certain term?

For Example:

```
textbooks = {"math":("red", "large"), "history":("brown", "old", "small")}
```

With more terms and cases where the same thing might occur again, how could I say find all of the keys in which their value is a list containing "red"? In my example above, the only one I'd want it to find would be "math".

Comment: Tip: it makes life easier on everyone if you give an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  In this case, that means actually putting the quotes around the strings to make your example valid Python syntax, so that people can quickly copy and paste your code into their consoles to play around with it.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the quotes for you.

Answer (score 11):

```
[k for k, v in textbooks.iteritems() if 'red' in v]
```

It is Pythonic shorthand for

```
res = []
for key, val in textbooks.iteritems():
    if 'red' in val:
        res.append(key)
```

See list [comprehension in Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Thanks for the link but it doesn't help me to understand where these variables come from or what they represent...

Comment: What variables? `red` and `texbooks` are from your question. `k, v` is from the `for` loop, they represent key and value of the dict items, in your case items are (math, (red, large)) and (history, (brown, old, small)), first element is key, the second is value.

Comment: Also you probably should read about sequence unpacking [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Comment: So can key and val be named anything and it should work? I am getting an inexplicable list index out of range error. Do I need to add any looping to prevent this? Or is it something else?

Comment: variable names do not matter - as long as they are consistent (ideally, they should be longer than 1 letter, but within list comprehension it is not such a sin). There is a loop in plain view in the comprehension - see the word _for_

Comment: I do see that. DO I need to add another one? The reason I ask is because Im getting an out of range error and Im wondering if it is going past the number of values in the list

Answer (score 1):

```
[key for key, corresponding_list in textbook.items() if 'red' in corresponding_list]
```