# How to check if value exists, in multiple lists in a dictionary, and get corresponding key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
directions = {"north": ["n", "N", "north", "North"],
              "south": ["s", "S", "south", "South"],
              "east": ["e", "E", "east", "East"],
              "west": ["w", "W", "west", "West"]}
```

I want to:
1) check if a variable (direction) exists at all in any of the lists in the dictionary
2) get the dictionary key of the list the value is in. How could this be done?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search Python dictionary where value is list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125950/search-python-dictionary-where-value-is-list)

Comment: if you're trying to convert n/N/north/North to 'north' why not have your dictionary the other way around, with any valid option as a key and then 'north' as the value for all of them?

Comment: The key words you want to google, is "iteration" and "string compare"/"list contains"

Comment: @Jaba - Well, I managed to get it working with two for loops, but I was looking for a more elegant solution. Stael's answer was just what I was looking for, and Chris's answer would be great in a case where I wasn't looking to get the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to take a stab in the dark and assume you are trying to take an input and return a direction - that's why you have 4 different formats for a direction.

If you flip your dictionary around it becomes useful:

```
directions = {"north": ["n", "N", "north", "North"],
              "south": ["s", "S", "south", "South"],
              "east": ["e", "E", "east", "East"],
              "west": ["w", "W", "west", "West"]}

useful_dict = {}

for i in directions:
    for d in directions[i]:
        useful_dict[d] = i
```

gives you:

```
{'n': 'north',
 'N': 'north',
 'north': 'north',
 'North': 'north',
 's': 'south',
 'S': 'south',
 'south': 'south',
 'South': 'south',
 'e': 'east',
 'E': 'east',
 'east': 'east',
 'East': 'east',
 'w': 'west',
 'W': 'west',
 'west': 'west',
 'West': 'west'}
```

now you just put any input you're 'searching for' into your dictionary:

```
useful_dict['N']
# 'north'
useful_dict['s']
# 'south'
```

Comment: ...and I could just use useful_dict.values() to check if the value exists. This was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @oneseventwonine only things to consider - this will behave oddly if you have the same value in multiple lists, and if you put a string instead of a list as a value in the directions dictionary. Just so you're aware :)

Comment: I say only things... there might be plenty more to consider that I haven't thought about.

Comment: Sure, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `in` to check if a variable exists in a list, and `for k,v in dict.items()` to iterate the dictionary:

```
directions = {"north": ["n", "N", "north", "North"],
              "south": ["s", "S", "south", "South"],
              "east": ["e", "E", "east", "East"],
              "west": ["w", "W", "west", "West"]}


my_variable = "W"

for k,v in directions.items():
    if my_variable in v:
        print(True)
        break
```

In this iteration, `k` will store all the keys of your dictionary (the `strings`), and `v` will store the relative value (the `lists`)

or, as suggested by @Ev. Kounis in the comment, you can use list comprehension:

```
print(any(my_variable in v for v in directions.values()))
```

which is more elegant, but you need to have a look on how [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) works.
you can also see the usage of [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), which returns `True` if any value in an iterable is true

Comment: or just `any(my_variable in v for v in directions.values())`

Answer (score 0):

If you are **only** interested in knowing whether the variable exists:

```
v = "north"
v in sum(directions.values(), [])
# True
```

Comment: This worked great for me, although I was actually looking for the functionality suggested by Stael, but could you please explain how it works?